# Strange behaviour in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, duplicates

I don't get it what the problem is, i have the following query:

Key Definition: id = integer(12)

```
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`id`,`name`,`ordering`,`state`,`category`) VALUES ('201310156239','geez','0','1','b')
```

Id is my Primary key, when trying to insert this SQL, i get the following error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

The number written here is not the one I want to insert as my primary key, how can this happen? What am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of integer is **-2147483648 to    2147483647** in MYSQL and you are violating the range.

Check this for reference. **[Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html)**